# What does "Wireless-men" mean?

Tags: meaning, german-language, all-quiet-on-the-western-front, erich-maria-remarque

In *All Quiet on the Western Front*, the narrator says,

> In the meantime we receive visitors, a couple of wireless-men, who are generously invited to the feed. They sit in the living-room where there is a piano.

Could someone please explain to me what "Wireless-men" means? I've looked on google, and I can't find anything remotely useful. It might just be because I'm bad at using it though :P.

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Radio operators?

Comment: Okay thanks :) is there any website with this definition?

Comment: Not sure if it's explicitly given anywhere, but that's the meaning strongly implied by, for example, http://earlyradiohistory.us/1917send.htm

Comment: http://earlyradiohistory.us/1909men.htm (written in 1909) uses the phrase "wireless men" three times, obviously as synonym for "wireless operator" (which it uses about a dozen times).

Comment: @muru Want to post an answer? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [original German text](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.168305/2015.168305.Im-Westen-Nichts-Neues#page/n235/mode/2up) reads, on page 232 in the linked edition:

> Inzwischen ist Besuch gekommen, zwei Funker, die 
>   freigebig zum Essen eingeladen werden. Sie sitzen im 
>   Wohnzimmer, wo ein Klavier steht.

The German word "Funker" means radio operator.  (From the German word *Funke* for *spark*, *funkeln* = "to sparkle", etc.  The *funk*  morpheme was used in the vocabulary of the   early 20th century development of radio, when the "spark gap radio" was the hot [technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark-gap_transmitter).  It  lives on in modern German in the words *Funk* = "radio",  *Rundfunk* = "broadcast", *funken* = "to communicate by radio", etc.  Cf. the English slang "Sparks" for a radio-man at sea.)

As several of the comments indicate, "wireless man" was used as an informal equivalent of "wireless operator" in the early part of the last century.

Comment: I've also seen the (possibly archaic?) German word "Funkmeister", which sounds like the stage name of a musician but is actually a radio operator :-)

Comment: "Funkmeister" sounds to me like a military rank/specialization, like "Master Chief Radioman"

Comment: Yeah, probably something like that. I saw it in the context of WWII paraphernalia; not sure whether the term is still in use.